# Difference between two ways of generating form path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an article and below it i have a form. I see that we can generate the comment form in two ways as indicated below.

**Way 1**

```
<form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

**Way 2**

```
<form_for [@article, @article.comments.build] do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

1. What's the difference between these two ways of `generating form's`.
2. Does the both form generate a same path, if so what is the preferred
   way?.

Answer (score 0):

First one generates a link to a specific comment to update it

```
/article/1/comment/1
```

second one generates a link to create a new comment on that article

```
/article/1/comment
```